# Generate Robot Framework documentation for test cases

Tags: robotframework

Is there a way to generate Robot Framework documentation for **test cases**?

I can successfully generate documentation for Keywords and Libraries, using `libdoc`, but when I try to do the same for `.robot` files that contain only test cases, I get the errors below.

Test case file:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   Suite documentation to appear on top of the html doc.
Resource        ../Root.robot

Suite Setup     Create Data
Suite Teardown  Delete Data
Test Setup      Go To Homepage
Test Teardown   Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
Test A
    [Documentation]  The test case documentation.
    Do Something
```

Errors when using `libdoc` on this file:

```
Try --help for usage information.
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/<path>Test.robot': Non-existing setting 'Test Setup'.
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/<path>Test.robot': Non-existing setting 'Test Teardown'.
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/<path>Test.robot': Non-existing setting 'Suite Setup'.
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/<path>Test.robot': Non-existing setting 'Suite Teardown'.
Resource file '/<path>Test.robot' contains a test case table which is not allowed.
```

Is it because the setups and teardowns are not supported in libdoc?

Comment: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-data-documentation-tool-testdoc

Comment: Duh, I should use TestDoc and not LibDoc.  Thanks @BryanOakley .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use `TestDoc` and not `LibDoc` for test case documentation.

Both tools here:
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/#built-in-tools